# unprotect sheet not working in excel 2013 (vba)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workook in which userform will pop-up only if somesheets as present (say Sheeta). On clicking submit in userform will do and some calculation and store it in Sheetb. I need to lock some cells from editing in sheetb.

code used in submit click

```
Sheets("sheetb").unprotect password="test"
'code for calculation
sheets("sheetb").protect password="test" , AllowFormattingcells:=true 'This statement locks the unlocked cells
```

The above code works fine when pop-up the userform through button say (loadfile).

I don't know what mistake I made.
Please help me to get rid of this...

Note : I want to prevent cells Sheets("sheetb").Range("N10:Q20") only from editing. Is it possible to prevent cells from editing without protecting a sheet.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to protect only Range("N10:Q20") and all the other cells on this sheet should be unprotected. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, if your goal is to protect only range "N10:Q20" on "sheetb" and leave the rest unprotected, then you can do that  very easily: simply select the whole range on the worksheet (CTRL+A), press the right-mouse button and go to "Format the cells.."; select Protection tab and untick "Locked" box. Next, select your range "N10:Q20" and do the same procedure but this time tick the "Lock" box. Now, run your code and you will notice that only your selected range will be protected, all the other cells on "sheetb" will stay unlocked and editable.